# How to print error it test body instead of hook after all in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, mocha.js

This is the first time I implement Before After Hook Mocha in cypress, and I notice the deficiency is Cypress is only print error in After instead of Test Body. My question is it possible to display the error message in test body?

```
  describe('Testing hook', () => {
    let a = 0
    let b = 0
    let c = 0
  
    before('This is Precondition', () => {
      cy.log('Precondition').then(() => {
        a = a + 1
        cy.log(`a = ${a}`)
        assert.equal(a, 1)
      })
    })
  
    it('This is main test', () => {
      cy.log('Main test').then(() => {
        //const dummy = 0
        b = a + dummy
        cy.log(`b = ${b}`)
        assert.equal(b, 2)
      })
    })
  
    after('This is Cleanup', () => {
      cy.log('Cleanup').then(() => {
        c = b + 1
        cy.log(`c = ${c}`)
        assert.equal(c, 3)
      })
    })
  })
```

Actual report:
[image: actual]

Expected report:
[image: expected]

Based on the source code above, I intentionally caused the test to fail, causing the after to also fail due to the connected data. However, as a user, when I run cypress and view the screenshot, I assume that the test failed in the After hook when it actually failed in the test itself. Therefore, I would like to know how to configure cypress to display the error in the way that matches my expected screenshot. Which settings should I modify?

Comment: You should probably put the Pre-/Post-Conditions to a Function, which then gets called in the respective Test.

Answer (score 3):

The error caused by the `dummy` not being defined is a javascript scripting error not a test failure.

If you substitute an expectation, Cypress will show you the the test failure.

```js
it('This is main test', () => {
  cy.log('Main test').then(() => {
    expect(b).to.eq(2)
  })
})
```

[image]

It would be reasonable to expect you to sort out the test so that it is ***initially passing***, and subsequently fail only when the page under test does not meet the test assertions.

Be aware that code inside a `.then()` callback is lazily evaluated, so that external variables like `a`, `b`, and `c` have the values assigned to them in previous commands.

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, the right way to go is basically not use `after` hooks, [mainly because they can be an anti-pattern](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks). Recommended practice is running cleanup logic in the `before` hook because every test should be responsible for setting up it's own state and not rely on other tests to cleanup their state.

Additionally, in the first screenshot, your `after` hook is throwing an exception anyway, so the exact error in your screenshot is the last error your test had, which includes the `after` hook logic. If you must use `after` hooks don't let them throw exceptions.

I agree the UI makes the error look like it's a part of the `after` hook, but if you collapse the `after` hook you'll see it's not actually inside of it. The error is just the last thing to be printed to the test runner console. I don't know any way to change this, it's best to raise an issue on [Github](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress)

[image: A collapsed after hook]

EDIT: Another thought too I had after posting, you should look into [Cypress's reporters](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters) and not solely rely on screenshots from the tests to see the errors. There's a chance with larger tests, if something fails, the error won't even be in the screenshot. Screenshots should be for looking at the state of the app when it failed.